# Stored Procedure vs Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have some data in my database on the server. I have 2 options to get required data from server:

1. Entity Framework automatic generated queries
2. Using stored procedure in EF.

Which option is better?!

Suppose that required data is some determined rows of a table that has a routine query with a single input parameter. For example suppose this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE someColumn = inputParameterValue
```

What's your suggestion? Writing a SP and call it via EF or writing a c# query so that EF automatically generates required query?!

Thanks for attention!

Comment: EF is of very less use if you don't write query in c#. But.. Always be profiling and write SP whenever explicitly needed.

Comment: What are your requirements?

Comment: Do you already have those stored procedures? If not, and if your queries are really mostly this simple - just use EF, it's perfect for this. It's fast to use, developer productivity is high, and it works just fine with SQL Server (using **parametrized queries**, it's safe from SQL injection and performance should be comparable to using hand-written stored procedures on the SQL Server side)

Comment: @Mark_s thanks a lot! Withdrawing the develop cost, which way is better? which way has better performance and more safe? execution and response time in which one is lower?

Answer (score 0):

There are other considerations, not just performance. You might like to ask what fits in better with your coding style of standards.

A couple of things I'd do would be:

1) profile the sproc and the EF call use SQL/Persistance medium profiler.

2) maybe inspect the LINQ emitted by the LINQ to EF provider, using LinqPAD for example (or - its only just occured to me to look at the SQL when debugging your solution on the context call).  And then make a judgement call.

Comment: Thanks @brumSource but my goal of above question is general comparison and I haven't just one case study to profile